# Can i create a struct inside the package to use outside in main program

Tags: go

I was porting my npm nodule to go package and at one place i need to do this.

```
type Credentials struct {
    key string
    responseType  string
    subscription string
    locale string
}

type WwogcParams struct {
    name string
    value  string
}
func main() {
    param1 := WwogcParams{"q","Delhi"}
    wwogc := []WwogcParams{param1}

    credentials := Credentials{key: "keykeykle",responseType: "json",subscription: "premium",locale: "EN"}
....
}
```

The main function here is basically what the user will have to write but what I was thinking if the user can use the struct I have defined inside the package in his main() function.

Why I can't use the structure outside its package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use uppercase names for the fields. Only uppercase names are visible outside the package.

```
package something

type Credentials struct {
   Key string
   ResponseType  string
   Subscription string
   Locale string
}

type WwogcParams struct {
    Name string
    Value  string
}
```

In main:

```
package main

import (
     "something"
)

func main() {
    param1 := something.WwogcParams {"q","Delhi"}
    wwogc := []something.WwogcParams {param1}
    credentials := something.Credentials {
        Key: "keykeykle", 
        ResponseType: "json",
        Subscription: "premium", 
        Locale: "EN"
    }
}
```

See [Exported identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)

Comment: meaning if I change "name" to "Name" I can use

package main

import "wwo" //my Whatever Package Name

wwo.WwogcParams{"q","delhi"}

Comment: exactly.   So, if you have type Foo struct { abc int }, Foo is visible but abc is not.  type Foo struct { Abc int }, now both are.   This is why you see in godocs (ie: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) the "contains filtered or unexported fields".  Click through the title and get to https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=53067:53192#L1780 where you see mu, m and hosts fields, all of which are unexported

Comment: Thanks, i am currently trying this and will accept as soon as it work.

Comment: Also note: You need to prefix the use in main with the name of the package (e.g. mypack.Credentials). The package should be in a sub folder of the same name as the package, and you should import the package in the main file (by specifying the path from GOPATH).

Comment: done and done... works awesome... published my first package worldweatheronline-go-client